# ¿Existe un método complemento (opuesto) a groupby en pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, revisión-de-código

En el siguiente código muestra un agrupamiento, sumando el total de ocurrencias, suponiendo que solo tienes `df2`, ¿Cuál es la mejor forma para obtener `df`?

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {
    "var_1":['a','a','a','c','c','c','c'],
    "var_2":['b','b','b','d','d','d','d'],
    "total":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    "days":['4','4','4','2','2','2','2']    
    }
>>> # Create a dataframe since a dictionary 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
  var_1 var_2  total days
0     a     b      1    4
1     a     b      1    4
2     a     b      1    4
3     c     d      1    2
4     c     d      1    2
5     c     d      1    2
6     c     d      1    2
>>> df2 = df.groupby(['var_1','var_2','days']).sum('total').reset_index()
>>> df2
  var_1 var_2 days  total
0     a     b    4      3
1     c     d    2      4
```

Comment: ¿revertir el agrupamiento y volver a tener los datos originales? si preguntas eso, la respuesta es no hay.

Comment: Si @PatricioMoracho esa es mi inquietud, veo, en eso caso voy a intentar con una función hecha a la medida, tal vez usando df2.appy(lambda x:my_function(...)) o cualquier otra.

Comment: Deberías hacer un función que agrupe, aplique el `sum` y a la vez concatene los elementos del grupo en una lista (columna), luego simplemente desagrupar sería "expandir" la lista. Es algo complejo, teniendo en cuenta que puedes mantener el data.frame anterior si quieres volver "atras"

Comment: vale, modifique la pregunta dado que esta tiene sentido solo si no cuentas con el primer DataFrame `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Create a column where each row contains a list of the same number of elements as repetitions of the row needed.

```
df2.assign(x=df2.total.map(lambda x:[1]*x))
```

Step 2: Use `explode` to split each list into rows.

```
df2.assign(x=df2.total.map(lambda x:[1]*x)).explode('x')
```

Step 3: Drop the column.

```
df2.assign(x=df2.total.map(lambda x:[1]*x)).explode('x').drop(columns='i')
```

Step 4: Set the total column to 1

```
df2.assign(x=df2.total.map(lambda x:[1]*x)).explode('x').drop(columns='i').assign(total=1)
```

Step 5: Reset the index.

```
df2.assign(x=df2.total.map(lambda x:[1]*x)).explode('x').drop(columns='x').assign(total=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var_1':list('ac'),'var_2':list('bd'),'days':[4,2],'total':[3,4]})
>>> df2
  var_1 var_2  days  total
0     a     b     4      3
1     c     d     2      4
>>> df2.assign(x=df2.total.map(lambda x:[1]*x)).explode('x').drop(columns='x').assign(total=1).reset_index(drop=True)
  var_1 var_2  days  total
0     a     b     4      1
1     a     b     4      1
2     a     b     4      1
3     c     d     2      1
4     c     d     2      1
5     c     d     2      1
6     c     d     2      1
```

Comment: Nice answer! pending task: translate the explanation to Spanish hehehe

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacerlo:

```py
# Copiar DataFrame para eliminar referencia a df2.
>>> df3 = df2.copy()
# Siguiendo consejo de expandir columna sumada 'total'.
>>> df3['expand_total'] = df3.total.apply(lambda x: [1 for i in range(x)])
>>> df3
  var_1 var_2 days  total  expand_total
0     a     b    4      3     [1, 1, 1]
1     c     d    2      4  [1, 1, 1, 1]
# extraer lista transpuesta.
>>> s = df3.expand_total.apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
>>> s
0  0    1.0
   1    1.0
   2    1.0
1  0    1.0
   1    1.0
   2    1.0
   3    1.0
dtype: float64
# Eliminar sub indice ya que no se necesita para el cruce
>>> s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
>>> s
0    1.0
0    1.0
0    1.0
1    1.0
1    1.0
1    1.0
1    1.0
dtype: float64
>>> s.name = 'total'
# Eliminar 'total' ya que sera remplazada en siguiente paso.
>>> del df3['total']
# Eliminar columnas temporal 'expand_total' 
>>> del df3['expand_total']
# Join by index
>>> df3.join(s)
  var_1 var_2 days  total
0     a     b    4    1.0
0     a     b    4    1.0
0     a     b    4    1.0
1     c     d    2    1.0
1     c     d    2    1.0
1     c     d    2    1.0
1     c     d    2    1.0
```

[Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows/17116976#17116976)

Comment: Podrias explicar esta respuesta?

Comment: Hecho, explicación entre líneas.